# How do I trigger the jQuery change event using only HTML DOM methods in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've asked this question in several places, and I'm now casting the widest possible net to see if there is a resolution I can use. Given the following HTML:

```
<select id="test">
  <option value="">Select One...</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

and the following jQuery event binding:

```
$("#test").change(function( event ) {
  console.log("Changed");
});
```

I would like to be able to have the change event triggered using only DOM methods. That is, I do not want to call the jQuery `.change()` or `.trigger()` methods to cause the jQuery change event to be triggered. This is within the context of a [browser automation framework](http://code.google.com/p/selenium), which needs to automate selection of options from `<select>` elements on any page, and thus cannot rely on jQuery being loaded in any particular page. Furthermore, we are only interested in a solution for this problem with IE, as we are only having difficulty with that browser. Also note, that we need a solution that will work for all versions of IE from 6-9. I would like to do something like the following (deliberately IE-specific code follows):

```
var e = document.getElementById('test');
e.item(1).selected = true;
e.fireEvent("onchange"); // What needs to happen here to get the jQuery event to fire?
```

This, however, does not cause the jQuery event to be triggered. You can find a full working example of this particular issue at [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/jimevans/a5DUE/). What is the specific code I have to invoke to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
var e = document.getElementById('test');
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
    e.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/a5DUE/7/ (works for me in IE9)

Comment: Nice idea, but support for `createEvent()` was only added in IE9. Is there a similar method (like maybe `createEventObject()`) that will work for previous versions?

Comment: The only other way i know is with  e.fireEvent("onchange"); (which doesn't work for me on IE9 so i thought that was the browser you had trouble with)

Comment: No, we're actually having trouble with all versions of IE. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: The fully working code is available at the link in the original question (http://jsfiddle.net/a5DUE/). This answer put me down the right path.